# Linux arp -a Output Table Column Definitions

Tags: linux, network-programming, arp

Could someone please define the header for each of these columns?

macOS High Sierra v 10.13.3
Input: `$ arp -a`

```
? (192.168.0.1) at b0:7f:b9:5a:d:a2 on en4 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.10) at 0:18:4d:ff:ff:7 on en4 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.15) at 9c:f3:87:ba:cd:80 on en4 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.18) at 78:28:ca:14:db:f0 on en4 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.24) at 38:c9:86:e:16:99 on en4 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (192.168.0.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en4 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en4 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.0.0.250) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fa on en4 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.192.152.143) at 1:0:5e:40:98:8f on en4 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en4 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

Sincere thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en4 ifscope permanent [ethernet]`
HOSTNAME | IP ADDRESS | MAC ADDRESS | INTERFACE | ROUTE COMMAND | ARP CACHE ENTRY STATE | HARDWARE TYPE

**HOSTNAME**: Apparently [if the hostname can't be resolved, you get a](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.networking/2005-12/msg00074.html) `?`
IP ADDRESS
MAC ADDRESS
**INTERFACE** or `Iface`: [Ethernet Layer Tools, Appendix B.1.arp](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-arp.html)
**ROUTE COMMAND**: In this case, `ifscope` is [used to bind a route to a specific interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/routing-tables-what-is-the-effect-of-the-rtf-ifscope-flag). [Routing flags](https://nbari.com/post/routing-flags/).
**ARP CACHE ENTRY STATE**: In this case, `permanent` refers to a [manually added address resolution](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_ARPCaching.htm).
**HARDWARE TYPE** or `HWtype`: Implicit reference from *Ethernet Layer Tools, Appendix B.1.arp*

Hope this helps someone down the line